# Functions defined in header / cpp file behaves different

Tags: c++

File: A.h

```
class A
{
public:
    struct x X;
    int show()
    {
        x.member_variable ? 0: -1;
    }
};
```

Now if A.cpp is complied which includes A.h (which is actually in a huge project space) we see that x.member_variable value is not as expected. But if remove the show() method and place it in A.cpp the code behaves fine - meaning that x.member_variable value is correct.

How such a thing may happen - one thing we saw from objdump is that if the function is defined in A.h the the method is treated as inline function which otherwise is not if defined in A.cpp?

How the code can behave differently altogether?

Comment: Well, that code should not compile. As a result, I'm having difficulty understanding the question.

Comment: "we see that x.member_variable value is not as expected" Well what value do you expect and what value to you get? These details may be important. Also, have you checked if the variable is being used while uninitialized?

Comment: The sample code is a snippet. Assume the compilation issue is resolved (x.member_variable is changed to X.member_variable - which I believe is not the point I am trying to stress here).

The issue is if we are having a similar type functionality in our feature (show method when defined in header file we see that value of X.member_variable is non-zero) but if we remove and keep the same code in A.cpp the value of x.member_varaible is 0. Please note that the flow is same. However objdump notifies us that show() method is promoted as inline function when within header file.

Comment: Inlining shouldn't change the behavior. So it sounds like either you have encountered some obscure compiler bug or you have some other problem in your code that somehow causes different behavior when the method is inlined. In either case, we don't really have enough information to help. Can you reduce your real code down to a simple, self-contained, compilable example that exhibits the same problem?

Comment: I completely agree with that. We are using gcc 4.1.2 version. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Let me add one more findings. When the function was declared in header file - using 'nm | grep show' listed me no lines but when the same in cpp file list me details. Is it because the function when treated as inline the inline function would be replaced the actual code. Will it impact anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Did you forget the `return`?

```
int show()
{
return x.member_variable ? 0: -1;
}
```

Without it, the code is still legal but the value returned will be somewhat random. There may happen to be a correlation between the behavior and where you put the code.

Comment: Thanks for correcting - it is the function returns 0 (success) or -1 (failure) and based upon that we branch out. But how the behaviour is different.

Comment: @Prakash: My code returns 0 or -1. Your original code returns a random value. That is how they are different.